# Queries against INFORMATION_SCHEMA time out

Tags: t-sql, timeout, sql-server-2000, information-schema

I am using SQL Server 2008 Management Studio to connect to SQL Server 2000.

```
use [MyPrettyDb]
select top 19 * from information_schema.tables
```

It works nice and sweet and quick. But this:

```
select top 20 * from information_schema.tables
```

Stops by timeout.

What is the reason for the timeout?

P.S. `select count(*) from information_schema.tables` returns quickly; there are 334 tables in the database.

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans for the two cases?

Comment: Why do you want 19 or 20 *random* rows from the catalog view? Perhaps you might consider adding an `ORDER BY` to give your query some meaning.

Comment: It's impossible. Th query plan out by timeout

Comment: OK. select top 19 * from information_schema.tables
order by table_name  - works nice. But select top 20 * from information_schema.tables
order by table_name  - out by time out

Comment: In addition I can add: no problem with hardware. A lot of disk space and 54% of memory usage.

Comment: New one: I tried to do it from MS SQL Management Studio 2005 from another server and everything works fine.

Comment: Well, I'm doing it in Management Studio 2008 and tried it with all kind of numbers, 19, 20, 44, 71, etc ... no success. I mean it all works fine without long response times. There must be something specific in your environment. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by my own.
The issue is only in Windows 2008. And 32/64 confilcts.

There are two odbc drivers in Windows 2008:
32: in System32 folder (or system)
64: in sys SystemWOW64

As I understood by default it using 64 version. But its not compatible with 32 version on remote machine. That why I had strange behavior.

Run odbc wizzard friom 32 folder and it magically become work properly.

Answer (score 4):

You are probably being blocked by a  DDL statement running inside a transaction. Run `DBCC OPENTRAN` or `sp_lock` to identify which session is responsible for this.

You can reproduce this by running the below script.

```
USE TEMPDB
GO

BEGIN TRAN
CREATE tABLE ttt(id int)
```

In another session, RUN

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES --will work

SELECT  * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES --will not work
```